# ogr2ogr select feature class from multiple filegdb

Tags: ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

From windows command shell how might I merge a single layer from multiple file-gdb's into another file-gdb using ogr2ogr? All input gdb's have identically named feature classes and attribute structures.

pseudo example:

```
ogr2ogr {input layername} D:\output.gdb x:\incoming\*.gdb
```

it's the *layername* part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: maybe `-lco FEATURE_DATASET=NAME`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In windows command line you could:

`FOR /D /R %g IN (*.gdb) DO ogr2ogr -update -append -f FileGBD D:\output.gdb x:\incoming\%g input_layername`

Just place the input_layername after the input dataset.

/D tells FOR to search for directories and /R asks it to do it recursively.

In a .bat file, replace the '%' with '%%', so `%g` > `%%g`

Extended batch file example using a) gdb's wrapped in zipfiles as data source, b) projecting to a new coordinate system, and c) selecting multiple input feature classes:

```
set ogropt=-f FileGBD --config FGDB_BULK_LOAD YES -t_srs EPSG:3579
set layers=Layer_1 Layer_2 Layer_3

for /r %%g in (x:\incoming\*gdb.zip) do (
    ogr2ogr %ogropt% -update -append output.gdb %%g %layers%
    )
```

Comment: This works. Where I went astray was thinking multiple input files were allowed, similar to *gdal_merge*. Also, much to my delight, input gdb-in-zipfiles work, although with hundreds of apparently harmless Recode UTF-8 errors.