# Merging multiple feature classes in file geodatabase with ogr2ogr?

Tags: sql, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, merge

Is there a way to merge multiple feature classes into one feature class in a geodatabase with ogr2ogr? If this isn't possible with ogr2ogr, is there another method? I'm using the [ESRI File Geodatabase driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html) for GDAL.

If the solution could merge all feature classes in a geodatabase matching a particular string, that would be even better!

**update**

org2org command I'm using to merge geodatabases, which works well but creates an unwieldy number of feature classes:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'FileGDB' -update -append merged.gdb gdbtomerge.gdb
```

Here is the structure of the geodatabase feature classes i'd like to merge:

geodatabase #1 feature classes (multipolygon) to merge:

Sec01_Frm01
Sec01_Frm02
Sec01_Frm03
etc...

geodatabase #2 feature classes (multipolygon) to merge:

Sec02_Frm01
Sec02_Frm02
Sec02_Frm03
etc...

There are no attributes for any of the features except for SHAPE_Length and SHAPE_Area for all feature classes. Ideally I'd like to give each feature a text attribute with the feature class name, but that is out of the scope of this question I think. Just merging all of the feature classes that either match the string 'Frm' or even the same geometry type would work.

**update**

I think I've gotten a little closer using SQL expressions with ogrinfo:

-drop a table (feature class):

```
ogrinfo -dialect FileGDB -sql "drop table tabletodrop" geodbname.gdb
```

-I tried this to merge two tables but I get: '(Cannot acquire a lock.)' with this command:

```
ogrinfo -dialect FileGDB -sql "INSERT INTO table01 SELECT * FROM table02" geodbname.gdb
```

Any thoughts on the lock issue or a better way to do this?

Comment: can you share the ogr2ogr code you have so far? This answer suggests merging on a field is possible if GDAL is built with spatiallite support: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/85046/9847

Comment: I don't actually have any code yet for the feature class merging. All i've been doing so far is merging multiple geodatabases. It works great, but then i end up with an unwieldy number of feature classes in the merged gdb. i was using: 'ogr2ogr -f 'FileGDB' -update -append merged.gdb gdbtomerge.gdb'

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to search comments for critical details.

Comment: I thought about that but then realized that the code I provided in my comment is not relevant to the question because it is a simple merging of two geodatabases and not the feature classes within the geodatabase.

Comment: @toms it looks like that example is dissolving features based on a field? or am I missing something?

Comment: Show schemas of both source feature classes and how you want the attributes to be in the result.

Comment: @user30184 I've added the schema above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To select a single feature class from a gdb, we query for all entities inside it:

```
-sql "select * from FEATURE_CLASS_NAME"
```

To generate a list of feature classes following your sample use nested FOR loops:

```
@echo off
for %%S in (01 02 03) do (
    for %%F in (01 02 03) do (
        echo ogr2ogr out.gdb in.gdb -sql "select * from Sec%%S_Frm%%F"
        )
     )
```

Emits:

```
ogr2ogr out.gdb in.gdb -sql "select * from Sec01_Frm01"
ogr2ogr out.gdb in.gdb -sql "select * from Sec01_Frm02"
ogr2ogr out.gdb in.gdb -sql "select * from Sec01_Frm03"
ogr2ogr out.gdb in.gdb -sql "select * from Sec02_Frm01"
...
```

From there add `-nln OUT_LAYER_NAME` to say we want it all going to one place, and `-nlt multipolygon` for geometry type. (NB: nlt is often automatically derived from input, but for some operations like this one geometry is omitted and you get just a table):

```
ogr2ogr out.gdb in.gdb -nln Form01 -nlt multipolygon -sql ...
```

And finally we will be updating existing data so:

```
ogr2ogr out.gdb in.gdb -update -append -nln ...
```

Useful [options](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html):

```
-config FGDB_BULK_LOAD YES
-skipfailures
```

---

How do I include the source filename in a field when merging hundreds of shapefiles (Windows)?

```
for %f in (*.shp) do (
    ogr2ogr -sql "select *, '%~nf' as s_file from %~nf" -update -append merged\output.shp %f -nln output
    )
```

---

Sources

- http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html
- http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html
- https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQVector

---

By the way, if you still have the gdb with the "unwieldy number of feature classes" hanging around from previous attempts you might be able to just `ogr2ogr -f FileGDB clean.gdb unwieldy.gdb -nln Clean_Form01 -nlt multipolygon` in one go.

---

Code samples are in Windows batch file syntax.
Thank you for this question. It prompted me to extend a [related project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140530/ogr2ogr-select-feature-class-from-multiple-filegdb) that I've been needing to come back to.

I don't think ogrinfo can write, so that would be the origin of the lock error in the Dec 11 update.